# Spock: How to let static method which is not in the class under test return certain value?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am using Spock with Groovy to test a class:

```
public class Animal {
    public void findAnimal() {
        findAnimalInZoo();     
    }

    private void findAnimalInZoo() {
        if (!isGoodWeather) {
            throw Exception;
        }
    }

    private boolean isGoodWeather() {
        return "good".equals(Weather.getWeather());
    }
}
```

and the `Weather` class:

```
public class Weather {
    public static String getWeather() {
        return instance.getWeather();
    }
}
```

Now in each test case for method `findAnimal()`, I want to specify the value returned when calling `Weather.getWeather()`.

```
def "when it is good weather then expect no exception"() {
    setup:
    // What should I do for Weather.getWeather()?    
}
```

How could I do it?

Comment: Wouldn't you mock/stub it as usual? Noting that the design used here makes the testing that much more difficult.

Comment: Could you tell how to mock/stub the return value of this static method every time I call it? I am new to Spock and have no idea for this and I have been stuck whole day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your production code is Java, then you can't use Spock mocks to mock static methods. If your production code is Groovy, you can use this:

```
GroovyMock(Weather, global: true)
Weather.getWeather() >> "good"
```

If you're stuck with Java, then you need to use Powermock or JMockit to achieve this.

```
def "when it is good weather then expect no exception"() {
    setup:
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Weather)
    when(Account.getWeather()).thenReturn("good")
}
```

Reference:
https://dzone.com/articles/mocking-static-methods-groovy

**PEDANTRY WARNING**
I know you are not always in the position to control or improve the code you are testing, so take this advice with that caveat.

When you need to go to such lengths to test your code, your code is screaming at you, that it is poorly designed. Your code is very tightly coupled to the Weather class. It is impossible to switch it out for something else, unless you do tricks with the VM, by rewriting classes. This means not only that your test code can't do this, but that your production code is unnecessarily inflexible.

Comment: If I could upvote twice, I would, Luis! I would have answered the same, especially the warning about using tools such as PowerMock in order to avoid refactoring. Writing tests is more than just making sure it behaved the right way. Test automation is a design tool, it helps to design better applications - better as in well-designed, maintainable, testable.